# variable definition by fscanf textfile.txt in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a textfile.txt containing variable definitions line by line, e.g. length = 1.1m

Using `fscanf` I want to store in my variable `double length` the value 1.1

Can someone give me some hints how to use fscanf in this case having a '=' seperator ?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Here is an exemplary inputfile.txt showing its structure:

```
[elements]
Number of elements = 2
length_1 = 1.5m
length_2 = 2.1m
velocity_1 = 0.35m/s
velocity_2 = 0.11m/s

[cells]
Number of cells = 2
cell_1 = 0.0m
cell_2 = 1.3m
```

I want to extract the parameters of both sections to two different structs.

Comment: Yes, don't use `fscanf()`. Use `fgets()` and `strtok()` and finally `sscanf()` or `strtod()`.

Comment: if the form is always like `length = 1.1m` that means a word (a string without spaces nor tab, newline..) for the variable, then a space, then =, then a value then a word for the unity. So the format of `fscanf` is obvious

Comment: You can't convert the string `"length"` to a variable name. You have to already have one by that name, or, build a `struct` with the id name and the value. If you also have definitions like `"width = 2.3m"` then perhaps you want to extract the data into other specific variables, or arrays. Anyway the problem definition is too broad.

Comment: thanks @bruno, I can read the values now using: ```fscanf(file, "%*s %*s %s ", word)==1``` and word being ````word = char[100]``` resulting in extracting the values + unity. Is there a way to omit the unity (I have variables with different unities, e.g. m, m/s ,...)

Comment: last `%s` can be `%lg` to get your double rather than the string containing it. But are you sure you can lost var name and unity ?

Comment: I didnt't tell the whole problem yet: My textfile.txt is not containing only variables with format ```variable = 5m\s```. Also there are some variables like ```number of elements = 2``` (where i **cannot change** the variable name to one string like number_of_elements). Also there are some sections (paragraphs) to structure the variables by ```[section]```. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: except the fact the 'var' name can contains spaces the form is still `<name><space(s)>=<value><optional unity>`, and you can manage that. If you want a solution fully working you need to explain all is possible to find in your input file, *and* what you want to extract/save, editing your question

Comment: after your edit it seems strange to have `Number of elements = 18` followed by only 2 elements rather than 18 or may be only 1 element if length and velocity are for the same element because both finish by _1. Of course same for cell. Are sections predefined or file can contains any sections ?

Comment: ah okay I think I understand what you mean. I just put random numbers as an example, I change them to more realistic values!!

Comment: @DagobertAmmersee but do you have only elements and cells with the variables (fields) you give ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. My inputfile is structured as posted above: there are some sections to give the parameters a structure, e.g called [cells], [elements]. These sections contain some parameters related to the section names. For each of those sections I will create a struct (in my main C program), where each of these structs contains the same variables as in the inputfile.

Comment: ```struct Elements
{
    int n_elements;    double length_1;    double velocity_1;    double length_2;      double velocity_2;
};```

Comment: @DagobertAmmersee no, you cannot suppose you always have 2 elements I suppose, I will put an answer ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Sure, the number of elements can be variable, depending on the given value in the textfile.txt. But for my example it won't change - we can assume it as a const given value. So did you understand my problem - actually I just want to read the input data (provided in the inputfile.txt) and set the values in the structs ( which have the identical structure as in the inputfile). Did I describe my problem understandable enough?

Comment: in `struct Elements {     int n_elements;    double length_1;    double velocity_1;    double length_2;      double velocity_2; };` you suppose you have 2 elements but that number is unknown, the struct must manage one element and you need an array of it, see my answer

Comment: @DagobertAmmersee it is clear for you ? (note I edited my answer to add an error case I missed)

Comment: thanks a lot for your work @bruno!! I'm still trying to understand your code and adopt it to my specific case. In case questions arise I'll let you know. Best regards!

Comment: @DagobertAmmersee so ?

Comment: Hi bruno, I've adopted the code to my problem. Everything works. At the beginning I expectet there might be a more simple and short way to solve that inputfile reading. But I guess due to my individual requirements of the inputfile.txt it can't be done just in a few lines of code. And thanks a lot for your support though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a way to do, the two sections can be given in any order, or only one can be given, or even none :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Element {
  double length;
  double velocity;
} Element;

void * read_section(FILE * fp, const char * what, int * n, size_t sz)
{
  if (*n != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid file, several sections [%s]\n", what);
    exit(-1);
  }

  char fmt[64];
  
  sprintf(fmt, " Number of %s = %%d", what); /* notice space at beginning */

  if (fscanf(fp, fmt, n) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid file, expected 'Number of %s = <n>'\n", what);
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  if (*n <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "number of %s must be > 0\n", what);
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  void * r = malloc(*n * sz);
  
  if (r == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory for %d %s\n", *n, what);
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  return r;
}

void read_var(FILE * fp, const char * var, const char * unity, int rank, double * v)
{
  char fmt[64];
  
  sprintf(fmt, " %s_%d = %%lg%s", var, rank, unity); /* notice space at beginning */
  
  if (fscanf(fp, fmt, v) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid file, expected '%s_%d = <val>%s'\n", var, rank, unity);
    exit(-1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", *argv);
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("cannot open file");
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  int nelts = 0;
  Element * elts = NULL;
  int ncells = 0;
  double * cells = NULL;
  char line[32];
  int i;
  
  while (fscanf(fp, " %31s", line) == 1) { /* notice space at beginning of format */
    if (!strcmp(line, "[elements]")) {
      elts = read_section(fp, "elements", &nelts, sizeof(*elts));
      for (i = 0; i != nelts; ++i)
        read_var(fp, "length", "m", i+1, &elts[i].length);
      for (i = 0; i != nelts; ++i)
        read_var(fp, "velocity", "m/s", i+1, &elts[i].velocity);
    }
    else if  (!strcmp(line, "[cells]")) {
      cells = read_section(fp, "cells", &ncells, sizeof(*cells));
      for (i = 0; i != ncells; ++i)
        read_var(fp, "cell", "m", i+1, &cells[i]);
    }
    else {
      fputs("invalid file, section header expected\n", stderr);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  
  fclose(fp);
  
  /* to check */
  
  printf("%d elements:\n", nelts);
  for (i = 0; i != nelts; ++i)
    printf("%d) length=%g, velocity=%g\n", i, elts[i].length, elts[i].velocity);
  
  printf("\n%d cells:", ncells);
  for (i = 0; i != ncells; ++i)
    printf(" %g", cells[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  
  free(elts);
  free(cells);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the space at the beginning of the formats when it is needed to bypass newlines (and possible other spaces).

Compilation and executions with your example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall x.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f1
[elements]
Number of elements = 2
length_1 = 1.5m
length_2 = 2.1m
velocity_1 = 0.35m/s
velocity_2 = 0.11m/s

[cells]
Number of cells = 2
cell_1 = 0.0m
cell_2 = 1.3m
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f1
2 elements:
0) length=1.5, velocity=0.35
1) length=2.1, velocity=0.11

2 cells: 0 1.3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

exchanging section order

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f2
[cells]
Number of cells = 2
cell_1 = 0.0m
cell_2 = 1.3m
[elements]
Number of elements = 2
length_1 = 1.5m
length_2 = 2.1m
velocity_1 = 0.35m/s
velocity_2 = 0.11m/s
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f2
2 elements:
0) length=1.5, velocity=0.35
1) length=2.1, velocity=0.11

2 cells: 0 1.3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

only elements

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f3
[elements]
Number of elements = 2
length_1 = 1.5m
length_2 = 2.1m
velocity_1 = 0.35m/s
velocity_2 = 0.11m/s

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f3
2 elements:
0) length=1.5, velocity=0.35
1) length=2.1, velocity=0.11

0 cells:
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

only cells

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f4
[cells]
Number of cells = 2
cell_1 = 0.0m
cell_2 = 1.3m
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f4
0 elements:

2 cells: 0 1.3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

empty input file

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out /dev/null
0 elements:

0 cells:
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

more elements and cells

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
[elements]
Number of elements = 3
length_1 = 1.5m
length_2 = 2.1m
length_3 = 1.1m
velocity_1 = 0.35m/s
velocity_2 = 0.11m/s
velocity_3 = 0.33m/s

[cells]
Number of cells = 5
cell_1 = 0.0m
cell_2 = 1.3m
cell_3 = 2.3m
cell_4 = 3.3m
cell_5 = 4.3m
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f
3 elements:
0) length=1.5, velocity=0.35
1) length=2.1, velocity=0.11
2) length=1.1, velocity=0.33

5 cells: 0 1.3 2.3 3.3 4.3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

and the possible error cases are checked, I encourage you to never suppose all is always ok but to check it is

To finish if you are under Linux/Unix check your program running under *valgrind*, for instance :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out f
==13981== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13981== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13981== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13981== Command: ./a.out f
==13981== 
3 elements:
0) length=1.5, velocity=0.35
1) length=2.1, velocity=0.11
2) length=1.1, velocity=0.33

5 cells: 0 1.3 2.3 3.3 4.3
==13981== 
==13981== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13981==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13981==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 5,560 bytes allocated
==13981== 
==13981== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13981== 
==13981== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==13981== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple program to read a formatted file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    float length;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("The file was failed to open.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%*s %*s %f", &length) == 1)
        printf("%f", length);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that we've used

```
%*s %*s %f
```

format `%*s` string skips the word from reading it.

The file `data.txt` looks something like:

```
length = 5.324325m
```

Then you will get an output of:

```
5.324325
```

You can now clearly see the strings are truncated and the value is successfully assigned to the variable.

Comment: what about to also give a solution also saving the var name and unity, and an other one working even without spaces at least before the '='  ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if your text file is something like this:

```
length = 1.2m
length = 3.4m
length = 12.4m
```

Then you can read it using this code:

```
FILE* filePtr = fopen("textfile.txt","r"); 
if (filePtr==NULL) 
{ 
    printf("no such file."); 
    return 0; 
} 
  
float num; 
while (fscanf(filePtr,"length = %f", &num)==1) 
    printf("%f\n", num);
fclose(filePtr);
```

For more information for reading from file, check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/)

Comment: supposing always `length = ` before the value is a big assumption ...

Comment: @bruno  I assumed that file is ideal and in form of what I said at the first of the answer (To keep the answer simple), but you're right, we should TAKE CARE of that

Comment: out of the 'perfect' file for me you cannot suppose the var name is always 'length', because the statement speak about `variable definitions` (plural). So I encourage you to edit your answer to propose additional ways to do each time with the associated assumption you make about file content. Also OP wants a `double` rather than a `float`

Comment: hanks to everyone who gave advice so far, great! I've edited my original question above showing an exemplary inputfile.txt. Note that I have different sections and also 2 types of formats for the variables. Can I filter somehow fscanf only lines in section [elements], then store these values in my struct elements and then go to section [cells] and do the same thing?